# Error: Cannot find module 'build/addon.node'

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to import a module using a non-relative import but it's not working:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "build/js",
    "baseUrl": "."
    // "paths": {
    //   "@build/*": ["./build/*"]
    // }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build-releases", "addons"]
}
```

Code:

```
// const addon = require('../../../build/addon.node');
const addon = require('build/addon.node');
const debug = true;

export { addon, debug };
```

The commented code works but the non-commented require does not.

This error outputs:

```
App threw an error during load
Error: Cannot find module 'build/addon.node'
Require stack:
- /Users/name/Desktop/workspace/proj/build/js/vapp/globals.js
```

Dir structure:

```
tree build/
build/
├── addon.node
└── js
    └── vapp
        ├── client.js
        ├── client.js.map
        ├── globals.js
        ├── globals.js.map
        ├── index.js
        ├── index.js.map
        ├── utils.js
        └── utils.js.map
```

(build is in CWD)

#### TypeScript docs say:

> A relative import is one that starts with /, ./ or ../.
>
> Any other import is considered non-relative.
>
> Setting baseUrl informs the compiler where to find modules. All module imports with non-relative names are assumed to be relative to the baseUrl.

Question: Is this because TypeScript is not responsible for module resolution with a `require`? As in, it's a node related things vs. a TypeScript thing?

#### Edit

I tried running `tsc --traceResolution` and found no information about my require trying to import `addon.node`. That made me realize: TypeScript is likely not responsible for module resolution here, NodeJS is. It doesn't look like you can easily change the baseURL dir for NodeJS and I'd have to use something like Webpack if I wanted to transpile with different, aliased paths.

Comment: Where is your `tsconfig.json` in your directory structure?

Comment: root of the dir